# Regular expression to parse a string after second semi colon and before first hyphen

Tags: sql, regex, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I am writing a regular expression in SQL on Google Spanner. Following is the scenario:

I have a string `ABC : DEP : 050-G&H Sample - IJ` where I want to parse `50` from it.

Similarly, if I have a string `ABC : DEP : PQ-Word1 Word2 Word3`, I want to parse `PQ` from it.

I have followed two approaches to solve this:

**Approach 1**

I wrote a regular expression for it `:([^:]*)-`. This parses the above two examples in following way:

`ABC : DEP : 050-G&H Sample - IJ`  -  `: 050-G&H Sample -`

`ABC : DEP : PQ-Word1 Word2 Word3` -  `: PQ-`

**Approach 2**

I wrote `:( )?([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])*-`, but the space in the parenthesis is ignored in Google Spanner, and it throws an error.

I want to achieve this using the first approach. Please provide some suggestions for it.

Comment: Try `: *([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-` or `: *([^-:]+)-`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Forgot to mention, in case of `050` I need only last two characters, i.e. `50`. While in case of `PQ`, the output should be `PQ` itself.

Comment: Add `0*` before the capturing group, see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks. There is one more case, where `008` has to be parsed to `08`.

Comment: Then use `0?` instead of `0*`, but that does not sound clear now. To strip leading zeros, `0*` will work, and I think it is the most common scenario.

Comment: Yes Wiktor. Your suggestions has almost solved the issue. Working on this last one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, what is the actual requirement? Note you do not have many options with regex here as RE2 does not support lookarounds.

Comment: The requirement was to find the first two characters, like `09` from `009`

Comment: Reason why the second regexp did not work is "Regular expression passed to REGEXP_EXTRACT must not have more than 1 capturing group"...

You have 2 sets of `()` in your regex, there needs to be only one, or mark the others as non-capturing using `(?:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
: *0*([^-:]+)-
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yK7Zy9/1)

**Details**

- `:` - a colon
- `*` - 0 or more spaces
- `0*` - zero or more `0` chars
- `([^-:]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more chars other than `-` and `:` (to only match alphanumeric chars, replace with `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`)
- `-`  - a hyphen